# Seamless Responsive Photo Grid with Omega

Tags: javascript, theming, media

I'm trying to create a responsive full screen gallery based on quite a simple idea, but without success. Idea is to have full screen view of many pictures that are adapting to screen resolution responsively.

The idea you can see here: http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

I'm working on D7.20, Omega 3.x

And what I want to do is to have content type, let's say, "picture" and create a view, which is displayed in a fluid full screen layout and is shown in such a way like in a given example.

But no success, it looks like it should be simple, but I cannot manage to understand how should I change the CSS to make it work...

It is probably possible to make similar effect using jQuery Masonry module, but I would like to do this with only CSS.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible with CSS only. It seems in first look that it is possible without any additional plugin. But at-least I could not find out the way.

Answer (score 2):

I have a kind of similar issue. I was actually trying to display different packages where the packages div's had variation in heights. I tried to align them using css without any luck.

so I then tried Isotopes and that worked perfectly.

You should also try https://drupal.org/project/isotope it comes with Example Context Reaction for Isotope.

there is also https://drupal.org/project/views_isotope module

You can also use

https://drupal.org/project/views_fluidgrid
https://drupal.org/project/masonry
https://drupal.org/project/masonry_views

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Picture](http://drupal.org/project/picture) module? I've used it for responsively scaling individual images. I think it's worth a try in Views.

Comment: thanks for advice - Picture, Breakpoints and Breakpoint Panels look very good and I'll try them out. But in my case they can't help me here as I would like to get such an effect where thumbnails constantly filling the screen without any gutters while changing screen resolution or rotating tablet. Picture changes resolutions of images in "jumps" and it's not the way I want to do. 

Actually, after trying for couple of days without any results I am thinking to do that effect without Drupal.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a view, you can make a [template for the view](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7), and for each record of the view, and then use both html and css to style it as you want.